# при получение всех пользоветелей появляеться ошибка что нет доступа

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

При авторизации мы получаем токен, который вставляем в users, и после если ты admin то тебе выводиться список пользователей, а если ты обычный user то у тебя нет доступа. Прикол в том, что ни user ни admin не могут получить данные. Использую mysql базу данных, стырила все с видео урока, но там используют mongodb. Помогите пожалуйста.Пробовала передавать вручную данные в бд через исомнюю, но не помогло.

rolemiddleware.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { secret } = require('../config');

module.exports = function (roles) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      next();
    }

    try {
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "Пользователь не авторизован" });
      }
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secret);
      const userRoles = decodedToken.roles || [];
      let hasRole = false;
      userRoles.forEach(role => {
        if (roles.includes(role)) {
          hasRole = true;
        }
      });
      if (!hasRole) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "У вас нет доступа" });
      }
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res.status(403).json({ message: "Пользователь не авторизован" });
    }
  };
};
```

модель юзера

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    return sequelize.define("User", {
        userName:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        },
        password:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        },
        roles: [{type: Sequelize.STRING, ref: 'Role'}]
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'user'
    });

}
```

модель роли

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    return sequelize.define("Role", {
        value:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            unique: true, 
            defaultValue: 'USER'
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

}
```

authcontroller. соединение с бд есть

```
const generateAccessToken = (id, roles) => {
    const payload = {
        id, roles    
      } 
    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: "124h"})
}

async getUsers(req, res) {
            try {
                const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
                    host:
                    user: 
                    password: 
                    database: 
                });
            
                const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM user');
            
                const users = rows.map(row => ({
                  id: row.id,
                  userName: row.userName,
                  email: row.email,
                  role: row.role,
                  // т.д - перечислите все поля базы данных
                }));
            
                return res.json(users);
              } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(400).json({ message: 'Ошибка при получении пользователей' });
              }
    }
```

authRouter

```
const controllerDo = require('./Controllers/doController')
const router = new Router()
const {check} = require('express-validator')
const authMiddleware = require('./middleware/authMiddleware')
const roleMiddleware = require('./middleware/roleMiddleware')


router.post('/registration', [
    check('userName', "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым").notEmpty(),
    check('role', "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым").notEmpty(),
    check('password', "Пароль должен быть от 4 до 10 символов").isLength({min: 4, max:10})
], controllerAuth.registration)
router.post('/login', controllerAuth.login)
router.get('/users', roleMiddleware(["ADMIN"]), controllerAuth.getUsers)
```

[image: isomnia]
packege.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.1"
  }
}
```

registr

```
async registration(req, res) {
        try {
            const errors = validationResult(req)
            if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: "Ошибка при регистрации", errors})
            }
            const { userName, password } = req.body;
            const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            ...
            });

            const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = ?',
            [userName]
            );
            if (rows.length) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Такой пользователь существует' });
            }

            const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 7);
            const userRole = 'USER';

            const [results, resultFields] = await connection.execute('INSERT INTO user (userName, password, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
            [userName, hashPassword, userRole]
            );
            return res.json({ message: 'Пользователь успешно зарегестрирован' });
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(400).json({message: 'Регистрация не успешна'})
        }
    }
```

login

```
async login(req, res) {
        try {
          const { userName, password } = req.body;
      
          const connection = await mysql.createConnection

      
          const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = ?',
            [userName]
          );
      
          if (!rows.length) {
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ message: `Пользователь ${userName} не найден` });
          }
      
          const user = rows[0];
      
          const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
      
          if (!validPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Неверный пароль' });
          }
      
          const token = generateAccessToken(user._id, user.userRole)
            return res.json({token})
      
          // return res.json({ token });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(400).json({ message: 'Ошибка при входе' });
        }
      }
```

Comment: НУ так проверьте, что у вас в `decodedToken`

Comment: { iat: 1702400475, exp: 1702846875 } думаете не правильно генерирует токен?

Comment: Думаю тут не хватает данных о роли и по этому там всегда пустой массив.

Comment: ```  const generateAccessToken = (id, roles) => {
    const payload = {
        id, roles    
      } 
    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: "124h"})
}``` есть такой код в authcontroller

Comment: Странно, в теории все должно работать.

Comment: 3 дня назад все работало, но сегодня решила запустить, и нечего не рб(((((

Comment: А перезапускать проект пробовали? Малоли..

Comment: конечно пробовала

Comment: я без понятия что делать

Comment: А пробовали токен новый генерировать?

Comment: при каждой авториации генерируеться новый токен, даже если так я регестрировала новых пользователей, у всех нет доступа, думаю потому что roles пустой, хотя не знаю, думаю токен - инвалид

Comment: `roleMiddleware(["ADMIN"])`. у пользователя, который делает запрос, есть роль ADMIN?

Answer (score 0):

В файле rolemiddleware.js условие if (roles.includes(role)) возвращает false даже в том случае, когда роль пользователя сходится с нужной ролью. Должно сработать :)

**-rolemiddleware.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { secret } = require('../config');

module.exports = function(roles) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
            next();
        }

        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            if (!token) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: "Пользователь не авторизован" });
            }
            const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secret);
            const userRoles = decodedToken.roles || [];
            let hasRole = false;
            userRoles.forEach(userRole => {
                roles.forEach(role => {
                    if (userRole == role) {
                        hasRole = true;
                    }
                })
            })
            if (!hasRole) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: "У вас нет доступа" });
            }
            next();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return res.status(403).json({ message: "Пользователь не авторизован" });
        }
    };
};
```